# Cannot connect to Spring WebSocket: "Error: Unexpected server response: 200"

Tags: spring, websocket, configuration

I am using WebSockets from org.springframework.web.socket. In my Websocket config I have changed the endpoints from

```
private final static String TEAM_ENDPOINT = "/teams";
private final static String PAGE_ENDPOINT = "/pages";
```

to

```
private final static String TEAM_ENDPOINT = "/teams/{accessCode}";
private final static String PAGE_ENDPOINT = "/pages/{accessCode}";
```

The WebSocket with the PAGE_ENDPOINT works with the new endpoint as I expect. However, I can no longer connect to the WebSocket with the TEAM_ENDPOINT.

How can I find out what causes the connection to fail?

The whole configuration looks like this.

```
import ch.uzh.ifi.hase.soprafs23.service.GameService;
import ch.uzh.ifi.hase.soprafs23.service.LobbyService;
import ch.uzh.ifi.hase.soprafs23.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private final static String TEAM_ENDPOINT = "/teams/{accessCode}";
    private final static String PAGE_ENDPOINT = "/pages/{accessCode}";

    private final GameService gameService;

    private final LobbyService lobbyService;

    private final UserService userService;

    public WebSocketConfig(GameService gameService, LobbyService lobbyService, UserService userService){
        this.gameService = gameService;
        this.lobbyService = lobbyService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(getTeamWebSocketHandler(), TEAM_ENDPOINT)
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
        webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(getPageWebSocketHandler(), PAGE_ENDPOINT)
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler getPageWebSocketHandler() {
        return new PageWebSocketHandler(gameService);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler getTeamWebSocketHandler() {
        return new TeamWebSocketHandler(lobbyService, userService);
    }
}
```

In Postman I get the following output when trying to connect to the WebSocket with the TEAM_ENDPOINT.

```
Could not connect to ws://localhost:8080/teams/733851
Error: Unexpected server response: 200
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/teams/733851
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Request Headers
    Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
    Sec-WebSocket-Key: xLptMIlsi1Gwrg+aPVJzrA==
    Connection: Upgrade
    Upgrade: websocket
    Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
    Host: localhost:8080
Response Headers
    Vary
        0: Origin
        1: Access-Control-Request-Method
        2: Access-Control-Request-Headers
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Wed, 17 May 2023 18:57:17 GMT
```

Also, in IntelliJ I get the following information when trying to connect to the WebSocket with the TEAM_ENDPOINT.

```
2023-05-17 20:47:58.939  INFO 14548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-17 20:47:58.939  INFO 14548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-17 20:47:58.940  INFO 14548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

When connecting to the "/pages/{accessCode}" WebSocket I get nothing in the console.